# How to extract exact values from a raster file (TIFF) using a shapefile, using xarray to open the raster

Tags: raster, shapefile, geotiff-tiff, rioxarray, xarray

I have found a link online that extracts the values min mean max and median, this is using the zonal stats function.

```
sjer_tree_heights = rs.zonal_stats(plot_buffer_path,
                                   sjer_chm_data_no_zeros.values,
                                   nodata=-999,
                                   affine=sjer_chm_data_no_zeros.rio.transform(),
                                   geojson_out=True,
                                   copy_properties=True,
                                   stats="count min mean max median")
```

I want the actual value for that location, rather than the zonal stats. I want to add these values to a data frame afterward. Is there a similar way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

These examples might have what you are looking for:

- https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html
- [Extracting data within geometry (shape)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328128/extracting-data-within-geometry-shape/328320#328320)
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358058/144357